# Angular2: how to merge rxjs calls from separate components via http service

Tags: angular, rxjs

So I use `switchMap()` to cancel out HTTP calls and keep only the last call to the server... Here is the service:

```
function httpService(url) {
   // httpRequest$ stream that allows us to push new requests
   const httpRequest$ = new Rx.Subject();

   // httpResponse$ stream that allows clients of the httpService
   // to handle our responses (fetch here can be replaced with whatever
   // http library you're using).
   const httpResponse$ = httpRequest$
       .switchMap(() => fetch(url));


   // Expose a single method get() that pushes a new
   // request onto the httpRequest stream. Expose the
   // httpResponse$ stream to handle responses.
   return {
       get: () => httpRequest$.next(),
       httpResponse$
   };
}
```

and the component using this service:

```
const http = httpService('http://my.api.com/resource');

// Subscribe to any responses
http.httpResponse$.subscribe(resp => console.log(resp));

// Call http.get() a bunch of times: should only get one log!!
http.get();
http.get();
http.get();
```

This works fine for one component... BUT, the issue is that if I call `httpService(url)` from different components I will still get MULTIPLE instances of HTTP streams, and sure, it will only be a SINGLE  stream per component (due to `switchMap()` canceling out repetitive `http.get()` PER SAME component)... my goal is to have ALL calls from all components be canceled out and only the last one sent to server, be accounted for.

What I am missing is the ability to merge all the streams together from the different components inside of `httpService` and have `switchMap()` only deal with the last last last one...   tricky... :/

Comment: If I understand what you want to do you need to use services https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html and share one instance of `httpRequest$` instead of creating the `httpService()` in every component.

Answer (score 1):

Don't directly return observable from request, but create observable from data. Something like this:

```
function httpService(url) {
   const httpRequest$ = new Rx.Subject();
   let httpResponse$ = new Rx.Subject();

   httpRequest$.switchMap(() => fetch(url)).subscribe(data => httpResponse$.next(data))

   return {
       get: () => httpRequest$.next(),
       httpResponse$
   };
}
```

Comment: unfortunately I am getting just more xhr requests with this setup :(

Comment: Do you have a plunker with example?

Comment: I don't but I will set one up... tx

Answer (score 0):

constructor(private _http:Http, private appStore:AppStore) {

```
    this.httpRequest$ = new Subject();


    this.httpRequest$
        .map(v=> {
            return v;
        })
        .switchMap((v:any):any => {
            console.log(v);
            if (v.id==-1||v.id=='-1')
                return 'bye, cancel all pending network calls';                
            return this._http.get('example.com)
                .map(result => {
                    var xmlData:string = result.text()
                });
        }).share()
        .subscribe(e => {                
        })
    ...
```

and to push data in:

```
this.httpRequest$.next({id: busId});
```

this works great and I can now have a single service that I can pipe all network calls through as well as cancel prior calls...

see image below, as new calls come in, prior ones are canceled.
note how I set slow network with a delay of 4sec to provide all is working as expected...

[image]